# Turn off vibrate when charging wirelessly

Tags: iphone, charging, vibrate

When I place my compatible iPhone on a wireless charger, it slowly falls off the charger over time as vibrations come in from messages. I appreciate the notification, but not if it will cause the phone to eventually fall off the charger. Are there any other options besides (1) manually turning vibrate mode to ring, which sometimes vibrates anyway, or (2) manually activating Do Not Disturb?

Comment: You might consider suggesting this to Apple as feature request here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

Build a stockade.

Cabinet maker's supply stores sell stick on bumpers that are used to keep wood hitting wood on cabinet drawers and doors.[image]

The set below is from Lee Valley Tools.

Stick them on the edge of your charging device so that it can't crawl off, and then let it skate to it's heart's content.